# RegExp.test returns false even though it should be true

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write this simple code into chrome live test and can't get it to return true.

```
var regExS = new RegExp("\d+x\d+");
regExS.test(" 240x120 (399.00)");
```

Even if I change the value to "240x120" it returns false. I've been googling and looking around and can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `var regExS = new RegExp("\d+x\d+");` is `/d+xd+/`.
You need to escape the backslashes when building a regex from a string:

```
var regExS = new RegExp("\\d+x\\d+");
```

or you could use a regex literal

```
var regExS = /\d+x\d+/;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a `RegExp` from a string, the backslashes will need to be escaped (`"\d"` is the same as `"d"`):

```
var regExS = new RegExp("\\d+x\\d+");
```

Alternatively you can use a regular expression literal:

```
var regExS = /\d+x\d+/;
```